# Space in Directory for WebSphere MQ FTE transfer

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

We are currently transitioning to WebSphere MQ (Version: 7.5.0.1).  For several transfer templates, we are getting BFGIO0110E: File "Source Destination" does not exist.  The location exist, but there is a space in the directory name.  If we remove the space, the transfer template job works fine.  Has anyone seen this issue?  We contacted IBM and they don't seem to be able to help.

Comment: How did you create the template? Was it via fteCreateTemplate or via the MQ Explorer plugin? You say that if you remove the space then the transfer template works, does this mean you modify the template as well?

Comment: MQ Explorer Plugin.  And yes, I have 1 job that had this issue.  We modified the template and the source directory (removing the space), and the job ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a transfer template via the MQ explorer plugin with a space in the directory of my source and the transfer executes as expected. If I then modified the template and placed quotes ("") around the source location then the transfer fails.

Can you confirm that the source location does not contain any quotes when you enter the location.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with and without quotes.  No luck regardless.  But it is interesting to know that you have been able to get it to work with spaces in the directory name. I initially created 5 jobs with spaces (not knowing about this error) and not one of them succeeded.  We are using FTP to connect to the data source.  IBM is still not responding.  Maybe there's some weird about how our environment is setup.

Comment: ahh you mean the source location is an FTP location rather than just a location on your local disk? Are you using the MFT Bridge Agent or a standard agent?

Comment: We use the Protocol Bridge agent to establish communication to external FTP servers.

Comment: If you are using the Protocol Bridge agent then the issue with the spaces in the path to the source file is down to the FTP server rather than MQ MFT. MFT just passes the request for the file using the Apache commons FTP client, and the result is that the FTP server reports no such file is seen. Your options are to either make sure no spaces are in the path to the file or use a different FTP server.